# How to configure ssh to use different key?

Tags: ssh, sudo

Hello I am trying to figure out how to make ssh use a different key id.  I can ssh into the server fine but if I have a script that is run with `sudo` privileges I get prompted for the password.  I can get around this by copying my ssh keys into roots `.ssh` folder but I know there is a better way to do this I just can't seem to find the answer.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I have already tried setting sudo to keep environmental variables ie. HOME

Comment: It seems to me that you may want your script to use `sudo -u youruser ssh ...` to do the `ssh` command. Root shouldn't really be used to access other systems. You could obviously also just use the `-i` option to `ssh` to pick up the correct key, but you never say why this isn't an option.

Comment: I guess I could use the `-i` flag I had this working before re installation I just can't remember how we had it done before, until then thanks for the reminder of the `-i` flag.  I am fairly certain there is a configuration of maybe it was a variable you can set to have ssh use the same key for everything.

Comment: The issue here is not so much to get `ssh` to "use the same key for everything", but the fact that you are using different users to do things (your ordinary user, and root).  Things like SSH keys are dependent on the user you're using `ssh` as.

Comment: Yeah I guess I'll just use your original idea of the `-i` flag I know we did this differently I just cant remember but it works if it comes to be Ill come back and leave a message thanks.

Comment: The -i key is the way to do what you want.  You can specify the same option, called identity_file, in the ssh config file.  No version of SSH I've used in the past 20 years or so allows you to do anything like this with an environment variable, though you could put identity_file=${SOMEENVVAR} in the config file and then set the appropriate var.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hello I am trying to figure out how to make ssh use a different key id.

Either use `-i`, or set up `~/.ssh/config` to mention a certificate. The last one needs to happen in the HOME directory of the current user.

> I can ssh into the server fine but if I have a script that is run with sudo privileges I get prompted for the password

I agree with Kusalananda to (1) either switch back to the user, (2) don't run the whole script as `sudo` in the first place, but use `sudo` inside the script (which depends of course on what the script does, which you didn't tell us anything about).